# Why can't I pass a non-constant variable as a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, non-type-template-parameter

I am working with a library which exposes an interface to work with. One of the functions of this library is like this :

```
template <int a>
void modify(){}
```

I have to modify parameters from 1 to 10 i.e. call `modify` with with template arguments from 1 to 10. For that I wrote this code (a basic version of code, actual code is much larger).

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    modify<i>(); // <<< error on this line
}
```

On compilation I receive the following error

```
error: 'i' cannot appear in constant-expression
```

After going through some links on the internet, I came to know that I cannot pass any value as template argument which is not evaluated at compile time.
My question are as follows:

1. Why can't compiler evaluate `i` at compile time?
2. Is there any other to achieve the objective I am trying to achieve without changing the API interface?

---

There is another thing I want to do. Call modify as modify where VAR is the output of some functional computation. How can I do that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

What is the value of *i* (that is not a constant) at compile time? There is no way to answer unless executing the loop. But executing is not "compiling"
Since there is no answer, the compiler cannot do that.

Templates are not algorithm to be executed, but macros to be expanded to produce code.
What you can do is rely on specialization to implement iteration by recursion, like here:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int i>
void modify()
{ std::cout << "modify<"<<i<<">"<< std::endl; }

template<int x, int to>
struct static_for
{
    void operator()() 
    {  modify<x>();  static_for<x+1,to>()(); }
};

template<int to>
struct static_for<to,to>
{
    void operator()() 
    {}
};


int main()
{
    static_for<0,10>()();
}
```

Note that, by doing this, you are, in fact, instantiating 10 functions named
`modify<0>` ... `modify<9>`, called respectively by `static_for<0,10>::operator()` ... `static_for<9,10>::operator()`.

The iteration ends because `static_for<10,10>` will be instantiated from the specialization that takes two identical values, that does nothing.

Comment: @Emilio Is there a way to call modify<VAR> where VAR is a variable returned by some functional computation let say VAR= f() ?

Comment: @gibraltar: Only if it's C++11 and the function is marked `constexpr` (than you can just write `modify<f()>`). And note, that the rules for constexpr are pretty strict.

Comment: @gibraltar: Or if the function is not constant, but it's range is small, you can write something like `switch(f()) { case 0: modify<0>(); break; case 1: modify<1>(); .... }`

Comment: would be neat if the compiler could figure out that it's allowed to unroll the loop.

Answer (score 3):

1. "Why can't compiler evaluate `i` at compile time?"

   That would defeat the purpose of templates. Templates are there for the case where the source code looks the same for some set of cases, but the instructions the compiler needs to generate are different each time.
2. "Is there any other to achieve the objective I am trying to achieve without changing the API interface?"

   Yes, look at [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html).

   However I suspect the right answer here is that you want to change the API. It depends on the internals of the `modify` function. I know you have it's source, because templates must be defined in headers. So have a look why it needs to know `i` at compile time and if it does not, it would be best to replace (or complement if you need to maintain backward compatibility) it with normal function with parameter.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use of Boost.MPL please? I am not familiar with this library.

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked for an answer using [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl):

```
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/range_c.hpp>

#include <iostream>

template <int N>
void modify()
{
    std::cout << N << '\n';
}

// You need to wrap your function template in a non-template functor
struct modify_t
{
    template <typename N>
    void operator()(N)
    {
        modify<N::value>();
    }
};

int main()
{
    namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

    mpl::for_each< mpl::range_c<int,0,10> >( modify_t() ); // prints 0 to 9
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using **struct** or **Boost** it can also be done :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <int a>
void modify()
{
    std::cout<<a<<",";
}

template<int i,size_t... t>
constexpr inline void CT_for_impl(std::integer_sequence<size_t,t...>)
{
    bool kai[]= { (modify<i+t>(), false)...};
}

template<int i,int n>
constexpr inline void CT_for()
{
    CT_for_impl<i>(std::make_index_sequence<n-i+1>());
}

int main()
{
    CT_for<-5,5>();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you want to call the functions at run-time by their index and you can't change the API, you can consider type-erasure:

```
std::vector<std::function<void(int)> > func;
func.push_back(modify<1>);
func.push_back(modify<2>);
//... and so on ...
func.push_back(modify<10>);

for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
    func[i]();  //calls modify<i+1>();
}
```

Some points to mention:

- That's not what templates are primarily for, but it's a way to bring a static library to the run-time world. The basic requirement for this is that one works with homogeneous types (--if `modify<7>()` would return, say, a `std::string` the whole approach would break).
- The previous solution using type-erasure has an overhead. One can maybe get it faster by using function pointers, but still it will always be slower than calling the functions at compile time.
- One can (and should) also wrap the `push_back`s into another iterative static function to avoid the manual calls.

Answer (score 0):

**solution to error: 'i' cannot appear in constant-expression for the above problem**

[To read about constexpr click this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void modify(T a)
{
    cout<<a<<endl;  //to check if its working 
}


//func converts int a into const int a
constexpr int func(int a)
{
    return a;
}

int main(){
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        modify(func(i));//here passing func(i) returned value which can be used as template argument now as it is converted to constexpr    
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is imo not what the OP intended. First, making a run-time integer constexpr y just passing it to a corresponding function does not work ... it just can't. But even if it would, you would call `modify<int>`, not the non-type versions the OP asked for.

Comment: But template will be auto detected

Answer (score 0):

> I have to modify parameters from 1 to 10 i.e. call modify with with template arguments from 1 to 10. For that I wrote this code (a basic version of code, actual code is much larger).

Thanks to index sequence (C++14), and folding expression (C++17), and lambda facilities (C++20) you might do:

```
[]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
    (modify<Is>(), ...);
}(std::make_index_insequence<10>());
```

Can also be done with C++11, but more verbose:

- index_sequence might be re-implemented in C++11
- Fold expression might be simulated in C++11
- lambda might be replaced by regular variadic template function in C++11

> There is another thing I want to do. Call modify as modify where VAR is the output of some functional computation. How can I do that?

You cannot directly use runtime value as template parameter.

To "convert" runtime value to compile time value, you might use a switch:

```
switch (var) {
    case 0: modify<0>(); break;
    case 1: modify<1>(); break;
    case 2: modify<2>(); break;
    case 3: modify<3>(); break;
    case 4: modify<4>(); break;
    case 5: modify<5>(); break;
    case 6: modify<6>(); break;
    case 7: modify<7>(); break;
    case 8: modify<8>(); break;
    case 9: modify<9>(); break;
    case 10: modify<10>(); break;
    default: throw std::runtime("unsupported argument");
}
```

or with "array" (this one can be generated thanks to variadic template)

```
const auto funcs[] = {
    &modify<0>, &modify<1>, &modify<2>, &modify<3>, &modify<4>,
    &modify<5>, &modify<6>, &modify<7>, &modify<8>, &modify<9>
};

if (0 <= var && var < std::size(funcs)) {
    funcs[var]();
} else {
    throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported argument");
}
```

A more reusable way is to transform your variable into `variant` of `integral_constant`:

```
template <std::size_t... Is>
std::variant<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>...>
toVariantOfIC(std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::size_t var)
{
    std::variant<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>...> vars[] = {
        std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{}...
    };

    if (var < std::size(vars)) {
        return vars[var];
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported argument");
    }
}
```

and then

```
std::visit(
    []<std::size_t N>(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>){ modify<N>(); },
    toVariantOfIC(std::make_index_sequence<10>(), var));
```