# How can we use a variable of the type of the template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

In the code below, I passed both class type `R` and a constant expression of that type as template parameters. But clang doesn't accept that:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T, T t>
void foo(){ std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl; }

class R
{
public:
    int f;
    constexpr R(): f(15){ }
};

constexpr R r;

int main(){ foo<R, r>(); } //note: candidate template ignored: 
                           //invalid explicitly-specified argument 
                           //for template parameter 't'
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5e997988d9ff673)**

In `N4296::14.3.2 [temp.arg.nontype]` I can't find any restriction other than the non-type template parameter should be a constant expression.

Comment: Try this link hope it will help you

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081573/c-passing-a-variable-as-a-template-argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

§14.1 [temp.param]/p4:

> A non-type *template-parameter* shall have one of the following
>   (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> - integral or enumeration type,
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,
> - lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> - pointer to member,
> - `std::nullptr_t`.

A class type is none of these.

Comment: So, how can I ever call this function? I tried http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ad9847605eb82e0 , but it didn't work. There r was an lvalue reference to object. What's wrong?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7228d79935e25eef; or http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8c11e5ebeec3b7d

Comment: Ok, that's clear. Just to make sure, my example was wrong because `R` and `const R` was not reference-compatible, therefore `N4296::8.5.3/5.1.2 [dcl.init.ref]` couldn't be applied, wasn't it?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv And also because in `const R& r = R();` `r` is referring to a temporary. (It's a lifetime-extended temporary, but still a temporary.)