# Unable to instantiate generic function in a loop

Tags: c++

I have some generic function, which looks similar to

```
template<int P>
struct foo {
    static const int value = ...;
};
```

Now, I want to call this generic function in a loop. Like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    auto bar = foo<i>::value;
}
```

But I get a lot of error messages. Like

> the value of 'i' is not used in a constant expression
>
> int i is not constant

I tried to fix it with:

```
foo<(const int)i>::value;
```

But to no avail. So, what is wrong with that and how can I make it work?

Comment: it means *constant at compile time.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a variable as a template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081573/passing-a-variable-as-a-template-argument)

Comment: It means, the template parameter value, your `i`, should be constant expression at compile-time.

Comment: @Rene. So, it means that it is impossible to implement exactly what I want?

Comment: @Jacobian depend on what you want, you may need a array.

Comment: @Jacobian Well, it is, but not directly. See the link that Nicky C provided.

Comment: @apple apple. In what way I may need an array? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Jacobian you need to store these value inside a array (maybe in compile time) and access it. it would be more clear if you can provide a context.

Comment: @Jacobian Is my answer ok? Do you need more information on some specific thing? Usually if an answer provides the solution you need, you should accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it this way.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
  auto bar = foo<i>::value;
}
```

**i** needs to me a constant expression, so that the compiler can generate the code for it when it compiles your program.

Here's an exhaustive explanation of what constant expressions are:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression

---

Here's a segment from the site:

```
int n = 1;
std::array<int, n> a1; // error: n is not a constant expression
const int cn = 2;
std::array<int, cn> a2; // OK: cn is a constant expression
```

---

So to make it happen compile time, you need to make your loop into a template recursion using variadic templates.

Maybe you can understand what you need to do better if you read this example:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<int P>
struct foo
{
    static const int value = P;
};

template <int TIndex>
int call() 
{
  return foo<TIndex>::value;
}

template <int TIndex, int TIndex2, int ...Rest>
int call ()
{
 return call<TIndex>() + call<TIndex2, Rest...>();
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Test: " << call<1, 2>()  << "\n"; // prints "Test: 3"
}
```

---

Nicky C posted a link to another question. It has a good answer and I don't feel right in copying it here. Take a look at my working example above and then look at the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11081785/493298

You should be able to make it work. It's a bit of a syntax hell, but you can manage it, I'm sure.